# MongoDB Null Query Anomaly

Tags: mongodb

Check out the following query:

```
 db.models.findOne({ "value.userId": { $ne: null } }, { "value.userId":1}).value.userId == null
```

This says:

1. Find a record that has a non-null user id field
2. Return the user id in the result
3. Compare that value to null

Since we're returning only records without null values, comparing the result of that to null should always return false. However, this *always* returns true.

If I just do the .findOne(...) and print that instead of doing the comparison, I get:

```
{ "_id": 4, "value": { "userId": null }
```

Anyone have a clue what's going on here?

EDIT: the "type" of this field is apparently 6 - not 10, which is what a null *should* be.
EDIT2: apparently type 6 is "undefined" - not sure why it prints null...

Comment: Strange this is. Because, it is giving expected result for me. Are you sure this is working this way?

Comment: Positive...just ran this: 
db.models.findOne({ "value.userId": { $ne: null } }).value.userId, and it returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the issue here is when you try to print an `undefined` value, MongoDB prints `null` rather than issuing you an error.

See this example: -

```
> db.foo.save({"amount": undefined})
> db.foo.find({"amount": {$ne: null}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d0d3a1511dd1035f01c636"), "amount" : null }
```

So, as you are saying, the type of `userId` is `6`, which is for `undefined`, so it prints `null`. Also, it is `$ne: null`, so it is matched too.

See this link: - http://realprogrammer.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/null-undefined-nan-and-missing-property-goto-considered-harmful-part-2/

---

However, if you see the same behaviour with `null`, you will get the desired result: -

```
> db.foo.save({"amount": null})
> db.foo.findOne({"amount": {$ne: null}}) 
null
```

Comment: Well now that's just annoying.

Comment: @jvenema. Well, that may seem annoying now, but actually this feature is very useful, when you accidentally try to print an undefined field, in which case you won't get errors. That is how MongoDB is designed to be.

Comment: I get that it's designed to "be that way", but the behaviour should be consistent - either print and filter nulls and undefined values the same way (*both*), or don't - but don't print one way, and filter another...

Comment: @jvenema.. Actually a field is `undefined` either by giving it explicit value of `undefined`, or when it is not there at all in the document. So, of course you cannot filter on the basis of a field that is not there, i.e., a `non-existence` or `undefined` field cannot be equal to `null`.

Comment: Sorta - in the find() call you can't filter on null == undefined, but in the console they *can* be compared (see my original question - comparing to null is true), and they obviously are considered to be equal "enough" for the purposes of writing to the output - otherwise you would see "undefined" and not "null" as the output of the script. The problem is inconsistency - in some cases "null" cannot be compared and is not the same as "undefined", but in others it is.

Comment: @jvenema.. As your output is already `null`, so you are not comparing `undefined` there, but `null` with `null`. What you get out of your `findOne` query is `null` and not `undefined`.

Comment: @jvenema. Well, actually you are right. `null == undefined` prints true on console. :(

Comment: So, it's OK to convert undefined to null in the output, but it's *not* OK to consider them equal for the purposes of querying? Seems to me to be highly inconsistent, is all.

Comment: @jvenema. This is really strange that I saw today. They are behaving differently in `find` and `console`.

Comment: It's because it's JavaScript - I spend my life in JS :). If you use type comparisons, such as null === undefined (note the triple-equals) will return false. So that's fine. The problem is that in some scenarios they're considered equal *without* type (such as the output) but not others (such as the find() input).

Comment: @jvenema. Oh Yeah! That is why this difference in behaviour I was seeing.